# No internet connection when using a managed network switch

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, home-networking, dhcp

I recently have run into some problems with my new NETGEAR GS108Ev3 Managed Network Switch where I can't access the internet without restarting the switch and even then it doesn't always connect. When it does work and I am connected, the moment I restart my computer I'm not allowed to connect again and have to restart the switch. The restarting of the switch doesn't work all of the time either. I also have an Arris G36 modem and router combo and it's set up with DHCP. Without the switch my computer connects via ethernet perfectly, but when I use the switch it looks like it can't assign an address or is refusing to. I've factory reset the switch multiple times and nothing works.

The funny thing is the switch worked fine for around 3 days connecting perfectly and then not working.
Any help on next steps or anything to try would be great, thank you.

Comment: It doesn’t sound like the switch. DHCP assigns the IP address and it sounds like DHCP is failing. The switch is not running DHCP, your router is. The router is the problem. Have you tried rebooting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, kinda.

It wasn't the switch as @Appleoddity said, it turns out it was my modem/router failing at assigning an IP address. I got a new modem and router setup, and everything works flawlessly. I'm not sure why the modem/router was having these issues, but I would assume resetting the DHCP settings would fix this issue. Also, as @Appleoddity said, the switch doesn't assign the IP address, this is handled by the modem/router. The switch simply passes along information received to both the devices and the modem/router.